# Security analysis tools for iOS 6

Tags: penetration-test, ios

Searched over web, however could not find much info on security analysis tools for iOS6.

Can somebody point me to the security analysis (Static Code Analysis & Pen Testing) tools for iOS6?

Comment: "Shopping lists", or requests for product recommendations, are not really a good fit on SE. Perhaps you'd want to rephrase your question along the lines of "how does one go about testing iOS apps" (more methodology-focused).

Comment: Its very sad to see the question being closed. With due respect, I have knowledge of how to do normal testing of iOS apps, as well as perform security testing, especially on iOS5. My question was very specific - wanted to know the tools which support iOS6.

Comment: I understand your point, however it has long since been discussed, hashed, and rehashed, many times over - long term, requests for product recommendations just don't work well. You could also pop in to the [chat] and have an open discussion there.

Answer (score 3):

I know this tool, but I almost didn't use it, might worth a check:

https://appsec-labs.com/iNalyzer

Answer (score 1):

The main areas of focus while assessing the security of iPhone applications (iOS6 and less) are -

- Application traffic analysis
- Privacy Issues
- Local Data Storage
- Caching
- Reverse Engineering
- Unmanaged code
- URL Schemes
- Push Notifications

Following resources may help you

- http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/02/12/penetration-testing-of-iphone-applications-part-1/
- http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/04/20/penetration-testing-of-iphone-applications-part-2/
- http://cryptocomb.org/Iphone%20UDIDS.pdf
- http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/01/10/iphone-forensics-on-ios-5/
- http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/05/using-keychain-to-store-passwords-ios-iphone-ipad